Fabricjs: Bounding Box is messing up with group.addWithUpdate() when scaled
I have fabricjs canvas with arrow like this:
addArrow() {
    const centerCanvas = this.getZoomedCenter(); 
    const arrowLength = 100; 
    const arrowHeadSize = 15;
    const arrId = 123;

    const arrowBody = new fabric.Line(
      [ -arrowLength / 2, 0, arrowLength / 2, 0 ],
      {
        stroke: '#FFF',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        selectable: true,
        evented: true,
        id: 'arrow_' + arrId,
        type: 'arrowBody',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        left: centerCanvas.left,
        top: centerCanvas.top,
      }
    );

    const arrowHead = new fabric.Triangle({
      width: arrowHeadSize,
      height: arrowHeadSize,
      fill: '#FFF',
      top: centerCanvas.top,
      left: centerCanvas.left + arrowLength / 2,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      selectable: false,
      evented: false,
      angle: 90,
      id: isImport ? importObj.id : 'arrow_' + arrId,
      type: 'arrowHead',
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1,
      lockScalingX: true, 
      lockScalingY: true, 
    });

    const arrowGroup = new fabric.Group([arrowBody, arrowHead], {
      left: centerCanvas.left,
      top: centerCanvas.top,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      hasRotatingPoint: true,
      hasControls: false,
      selection: false,
      hasBorders: false,
      lockScalingFlip: true, 
      id: 'arrow_' + arrId,
      type: 'arrow',
      perPixelTargetFind: true, 
      angle: 0,
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1,
    });
    this.canvas.add(arrowGroup);
    this.canvas.setActiveObject(arrowGroup);
    this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }

On mouse:down event, I am make the selection of that arrow group like this:
enableArrowAdjustment (obj) {
    this.canvas.setActiveObject(obj);
    let selection = this.canvas.getActiveObject();
    selection.set({
      hasBorders: true,
      hasControls: true,
      lockScalingFlip: true,
      lockRotation: false,
      centeredRotation: true,
      cornerStyle: 'circle',
      transparentCorners: false,
      borderOpacityWhenMoving: 1,
      cornerSize: 7,
      padding: 10,
      cornerStrokeColor: '#FFF',
      cornerColor: '#FFF',
      borderColor: '#FFF',
      hoverCursor:'default',
      centeredScaling: false,
      editingBorderColor: '#92949c'
    }).setControlsVisibility({
      mtr: true, mt: false, mb: false, ml: true, mr: false, bl: false, br: false, tl: false, tr: false
    }); 
    this.canvas.renderAll(); 
  }

Now when i try to scale the arrow group, I am scaling only arrowBody and unscaling the arrowHead like this:
var group = this.canvas.getActiveObject();
var arrowHead = group.getObjects()[1];
var groupScaleX = group.scaleX;
var groupScaleY = group.scaleY;

arrowHead.set({
 scaleX: 1 / groupScaleX,
 scaleY: 1 / groupScaleY
}).setCoords();
        
group.set({ 
 shapeScaleX: groupScaleX, 
 shapeScaleY: groupScaleY 
}).setCoords();

//Update the group (messes up the bounding box when rotated)
group.addWithUpdate();

this.canvas.renderAll();
this.detailObserver(group);

While this scaling works flawlessly and it scales only the arrow body but when i rotate my arrow group, and then try to scale the arrow body, the bounding box i turning into square and it skews the arrow instead of scaling arrow body.

Any idea what am i doing wrong?
